# webkit border image not loading mobile safari

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, css

I'm having some pretty strange problems on a mobile website. For one of my elements, I have the css property:

-webkit-border-image: url(images/speech_box_right.png) 24 10 4 10  stretch stretch;

This image never loads - using developer mode, the file seems to never be retrieved. What's strange is that on mobile user agent it always works, and sometimes it does load on my phone as well. I can also always load the image directly from my phone if i type in its filepath. Has anyone experienced issues with mobile safari rendering border images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

border-image is shorthand property for following five properties:
border-image: source slice width outset repeat;

In your code could see stretch given multiple times. can you removing that?

I tested in desktop Safari 5 it's working fine without any issues. border-image is supported in Safari 6 and Safari 5 supports an alternative, the -webkit-border-image property.